# TextIO.Write.to(..) - is it possible to specify compression?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I know it's possible to specify the compression type for the pipeline's **input** when using `TextIO.Read`, like so:

```
TextIO.Read.from("gs://..").withCompressionType(..)
```

Is it also possible to specify the compression type for the pipeline's **output** when using `TextIO`? I don't see anything about compression in the API for `TextIO.Read.from(..)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not yet possible to specify the compression type for output using TextIO. Thanks for noting your interest in this feature!